# I was trying to compute the lie derivative and I didn't find my result in the options under the question

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose $(V^r,V^\theta,V^\phi)=(r,r^2cos\theta, sin\phi), (W^r,W^\theta,W^\phi)=(r, sin\theta, sin\theta cos\phi)$

The metric is described by:

$G=\begin{pmatrix}g_{rr}&g_{r\theta}&g_{r\phi}\\g_{\theta r}&g_{\theta \theta}&g_{\theta\phi}\\g_{\phi r}&g_{\phi \theta}&g_{\phi\phi}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&r^2&0\\0&0&r^2sin^2\theta\end{pmatrix}$, $G^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&\frac 1{r^2}&0\\0&0&\frac 1{r^2sin^2\theta}\end{pmatrix}$

Then the Christoffel symbols of the first and second kind are given by:

$\Gamma_{r\theta\theta}=\Gamma_{\theta r\theta}=-\Gamma_{\theta\theta r}=r$

$\Gamma_{r\phi\phi}=\Gamma_{\phi r\phi}=-\Gamma_{\phi\phi r}=rsin^2\theta$

$\Gamma_{\theta\phi\phi}=\Gamma_{\phi\theta\phi}=-\Gamma_{\phi\phi\theta}=r^2sin\theta cos\theta$

$\Gamma^r_{\theta\theta}=g^{rr}\Gamma_{r\theta\theta}=r,\Gamma^\theta_{r\theta}=g^{\theta\theta}\Gamma_{\theta r\theta}=\frac 1{r},\Gamma^\theta_{\theta r}=g^{\theta\theta}\Gamma_{\theta\theta r}=-\frac 1 {r}$

$\Gamma^r_{\phi\phi}=g^{rr}\Gamma_{r\phi\phi}=rsin^2\theta,\Gamma^{\phi}_{r\phi}=g^{\phi\phi}\Gamma_{\phi r\phi}=\frac 1r,\Gamma^{\phi}_{\phi r}=g^{\phi\phi}\Gamma_{\phi\phi r}=-\frac 1r$

$\Gamma^\theta_{\phi\phi}=g^{\theta\theta}\Gamma_{\theta\phi\phi}=sin\theta cos\theta, \Gamma^{\phi}_{\theta\phi}=g^{\phi\phi}\Gamma_{\phi\theta\phi}=cot\theta,\Gamma^\phi_{\phi\theta}=g^{\phi\phi}\Gamma_{\phi\phi\theta}=-cot\theta$

I was trying to compute the $\phi$ component of lie derivative $L_VW$:

$V^r\nabla_rW^\phi-W^r\nabla_rV^\phi=sin\theta cos\phi-sin\phi$

$V^\theta\nabla_\theta W^\phi-W^\theta\nabla_\theta V^\phi=cos\theta(2r^2cos\theta cos\phi-sin\phi)$

$V^\phi\nabla_\phi W^\phi-W^\phi\nabla_\phi V^\phi=-sin^2\phi sin\theta+sin\phi+sin\phi cos\theta-sin\theta cos^2 \phi-sin\theta cos\phi r^2cos\theta cot\theta$

After summing the terms up I didn't find my result in the options under the question. Where was I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you simplify the trig? e.g. $-\sin^2\phi\sin\theta - \sin\theta\cos^2\phi = -\sin\theta$, to take two of the terms.

Comment: simplifying the $\phi$ component yields $-\sin (\theta) + \cos (\theta) ( \sin (\phi) - r² \cos (\theta) \cos (\phi) ) + \sin (\phi)$ does that help?